# Error in Itemize

Tags: itemize

I'm writing a report with few chapters. and When I try to run it in TeXstudio it's giving the error "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\NewCount`. `\begin{itemize}`.

My preamble is given below,

```
\documentclass[
11pt, 
english, 
singlespacing, 
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
 %\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters

\usepackage{palatino} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, natbib=true, 
uniquename=false]{biblatex} % User the bibtex backend with the authoryear 
citation style (which resembles APA)
%\usepackage[natbib, maxcitenames=3, mincitenames=11, style=apa]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Muhas_Library.bib} % The filename of the bibliohy

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language- 
dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage[normal]{subfigure}


\mainmatter % Begin numeric (1,2,3...) page numbering

\pagestyle{thesis} % Return the page headers back to the "thesis" style

% Include the chapters of the thesis as separate files from the Chapters folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the chapters

\input{Chapters/Chapter1}
\input{Chapters/Chapter2} 
\input{Chapters/Chapter3}
\input{Chapters/Chapter4} 
\input{Chapters/Chapter5} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter6} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter7} 
%\input{Chapters/Chapter8} 

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   THESIS CONTENT - APPENDICES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\appendix % Cue to tell LaTeX that the following "chapters" are Appendices

% Include the appendices of the thesis as separate files from the Appendices folder
% Uncomment the lines as you write the Appendices

\input{Appendices/AppendixA}
\input{Appendices/AppendixB}
\input{Appendices/AppendixC}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BIBLIOGRAPHY
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

When I compile the code at first, from my back ups, it works well. And when I copy a paragraph from another document to Chapter 2 which contains only texts and few citations, its giving error on the next chapter's (Chapter 3) `enumerate` command, which was working well previously. The error message is "Illegal parameter number in definition of `\NewCount`. `\begin{enumerate}`". Then again if I undo the change I made and try to compile, it's giving the same error. I don't know how to fix this and I'm desperately in need of a quick help as I have to finish my report soon.

I'm trying to create the minimal working example. 
But, in the meantime I unistalled both MikTex and Texstudio and then reinstalled them. Then tried to compile and it was working, except for biber not upto date and the citations didn't show up. Hence, I updated the MikTex from its console and then compiles and getting the old error. I think there is something wrong with the updates?

Here is the MWE I created and the screenshot of the corresponding error messages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, natbib=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Muhas_Library.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[normal]{subfigure}


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

 flows are induced by the variation in eitt flows, is popularly known as the convective flows. This is a combination of two branches of science, namely, heat transfer and fluid mechaniges in handling free surfhe computational cost.and later numerical studies (    ) have been conducted in a number of different domains, such as rectangular, triangular and wedge shape. They have considered a number of different scenarios of application of t

\section{Convective flows}

The , which is basically a force balance in a control volume.

\begin{equation}
\rho.\frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt}=-\nabla P + \mu \nabla^2 \textbf{u} + F
\label{equ:14}
\end{equation}


If the  ($J$), negligible viscous dissipation ($\mu \phi$) and negligible compressibility effect ($\alpha T \frac{DP}{Dt}$); $\alpha$ is coefficient of thermal expansion,

\begin{align}
\frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt} &= -\frac{1}{\rho_0}\nabla (P_\delta + \rho \textbf{g} y) + \nu \nabla^2 \textbf{u} + \textbf{g}(1-\alpha\Delta T)
&= -\frac{1}{\rho_0}\nabla P_\delta + \nu \nabla^2 \textbf{u} - \textbf{g}\alpha\Delta T
\end{align}


\section{flow due to diurnal}

One of the vital process wherein water the solar radiation penetrates the water, it's intensity aw ($I = I_o \exp^{-\alpha*y}$). In line with this law, the intensity of light attewater \citep{Farrow1993}. Thus in the shallow regions long-wave lengtpth, whereas short-wavelength ra

A recent review on absorption can be found in \citet{Amber2018}. 



\begin{enumerate}
    \item Improving the bodies.

    the present knowledge on this subject by revealing the necessary numerical techniques, modifications, adjustments and improvements. 

    \item  Developing a  flow condition.

     which will be efficient and effective in the studies of solid-fluid interaction under buoyant flow scenarios.  

    \item  Exploring the values of 

    Achieving this objective will unfold a modelling approach, which will be efficient and effective in the studies of scenarios.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{equation}
\langle \nabla f(\vec{x})\rangle=-\int_Vf(\vec{x'})\nabla' W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)d\vec{x'},\label{eq:kernel_gradient}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[-] $W$ is usually an even function with respect to $\vec{x}$, it is positive, having the maximum value at $\vec{x}$ and decreases monotonically with the distance from $\vec{x}$;

    \item[-] {\it normalization condition}:

    \begin{equation}
    \int_VW(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)d\vec{x'}=1;
    \end{equation}
    \\

    \item[-] {\it Dirac-$\delta$ property}:

    \begin{equation}
    \lim_{h\to 0}W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)=\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x'});
    \end{equation}
    \\

    \item[-] {\it compact support}:

    \begin{equation}
    W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)=0\ {\rm when}\ |\vec{x}-\vec{x'}|>\kappa h,
    \end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

New edited code with @Zarco's comments; but getting the same error :(

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp, maxcitenames=2, natbib=true, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Muhas_Library.bib}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[normal]{subfigure}


\begin{document}


\section{Introduction}

flows are induced by the variation in flows, is popularly known as the flows. This is a combination of two branches of science, namely, heat transfer and fluid  in handling free computational cost. and later numerical studies (    ) have been conducted in a number of different domains, such as rectangular, triangular and wedge shape. They have considered a number of different scenarios of application of t

\section{Convective flows}

which is basically a force balance in a control volume.

\begin{equation}
\rho.\frac{D\mathbf{u}}{Dt}=-\nabla P + \mu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} + F
\label{equ:14}
\end{equation}

If the  ($J$), negligible viscous dissipation ($\mu \phi$) and negligible compressibility effect ($\alpha T \frac{DP}{Dt}$); $\alpha$ is coefficient of thermal expansion,

\begin{align}
\frac{D\mathbf{u}}{Dt} &= -\frac{1}{\rho_0}\nabla (P_\delta + \rho \mathbf{g} y) + \nu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} + \mathbf{g}(1-\alpha\Delta T)\\
&= -\frac{1}{\rho_0}\nabla P_\delta + \nu \nabla^2 \mathbf{u} - \mathbf{g}\alpha\Delta T
\end{align}

\section{flow due to diurnal}

One of the vital process wherein water the solar radiation penetrates the water, it's intensity aw ($I = I_o \exp^{-\alpha*y}$). In line with this law, the intensity of light attewater \citep{Farrow1993}. Thus in the shallow regions long-wave lengtpth, whereas short-wavelength 

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Improving the bodies.

    the present knowledge on this subject by revealing the necessary numerical techniques, modifications, adjustments and improvements. 

    \item  Developing a  flow condition.

     which will be efficient and effective in the studies of solid-fluid interaction under buoyant flow scenarios.  

    \item  Exploring the values of 

    Achieving this objective will unfold a modelling approach, which will be efficient and effective in the studies of scenarios.

\end{enumerate}

\begin{equation}
\langle \nabla f(\vec{x})\rangle=-\int_Vf(\vec{x'})\nabla' W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)d\vec{x'},\label{eq:kernel_gradient}
\end{equation}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[-] $W$ is usually an even function with respect to $\vec{x}$, it is positive, having the maximum value at $\vec{x}$ and decreases monotonically with the distance from $\vec{x}$;

    \item[-] {\it normalization condition}:

    \begin{equation}
    \int_VW(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)d\vec{x'}=1;
    \end{equation}


    \item[-] {\it Dirac-$\delta$ property}:

    \begin{equation}
    \lim_{h\to 0}W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)=\delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x'});
    \end{equation}


    \item[-] {\it compact support}:

    \begin{equation}
    W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)=0\ {\rm when}\ |\vec{x}-\vec{x'}|>\kappa h,
    \end{equation}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your sample code a [minimal, self-contained document](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). You include a lot of external files which may or may not be part of the problem. Find a minmal document that reproduces the error.

Comment: provided document is useless. we haven't your files, so we can't test it. please (again). provide minimal working example, which will show your problem. off-topic: package `subfigure` is obsolete ...

Comment: The problem is in one of your included files. Start at the end and comment out step by step the files until the error is gone. Then you know what file is the problem.

Comment: Thanks every one. When I compile the code at first it works well. And when I copy a paragraph from another document which contains only texts and few citations, its giving error on the next chapter as "Illegal parameter number in definition of \NewCount. \begin{enumerate}". Then if I undo the change I made and try to compile its giving the same error. I don't know how to fix this and I'm desperately in need of a quick help as I have to finish my report soon.

Comment: @K.M.Muha Please read [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and make a small, but compilable document that reproduces the error.

Comment: As you can see from my edits to my initial question, I'm sure the problem is not with my writing. Also, every time when I try something different like commenting out the chapters indicted in the error, it gives error somewhere else.

Comment: for sure the error is in your code. you might have inside invisible characters in it, which cause your problem or some other error in your code. does included text use the same coding as you mine text? since your documents are still unknown, we can't help you.

Comment: @Zarko Then why is the code working before updating the MikTex?

Comment: @samcarter I have added the MWE and a screen shot of the error messages I'm getting. Thanks

Comment: (i) i cant reproduce your error (ii) however your use of `biblatex` is fragile: used option gives error (iii) you use more than 20 years obsolete font face commands `\bf`, (iv) package `subfigure` is obsolete (v) use of `align` is wrong (missed is `\\ ` after first equation), (vi) in math environment don't use `\textbf{...}` but `\mathbf{...}`, (vi) newer introduce additional vertical space with `\\ ` after equation (without them the itemize formatting is better) (vii) itemize works fine, (viii) in text you have spelling errors ... i test all with recent `miktex`, with editor WinEdt.

Comment: @Zarko Thanks for checking and finding the errors. Please ignore the spelling errors as I deleted texts here and there to reduce my writing and just have some text over there for MWE purpose. Can you please tell me how I can overcome the errors you have mentioned by (ii), (iii), (v)

Comment: shortly: your document has many issues. i'm afraid, that you need to check it 
 again thoroughly and repair all inconsistencies and wrong use of latex commands. btw, what mean `\frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt}`? usual notation for derivative is `\frac{d\textbf{u}}{dt}` or `\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf{u}}{\mathrm{d}t}` ...

Comment: @Zarko I implemented the corrections you pointed out and still getting the exact same error messages. How can I overcome this? Is anything wrong with my Miktex and texstudio?  Btw, \frac{D\textbf{u}}{Dt} is the substantial derivative, which denotes the changes in time and space

Comment: i can't say that. i beliwe that you need to check your files. they are buggy. for start try  the following test `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\begin{itemize}\item bla bla\item\bla bla\end{itemize}\end{document}`. if it works fine, than try extend this test with adding used packages and real content of `itemize` list. if still work fine, try to add package by package which you use and other (corrected) text from your files.

Comment: @Zarko what do you mean by "(ii) however your use of biblatex is fragile: used option gives error". How can I make it stong? For what you have mentioned here "(iii) you use more than 20 years obsolete font face commands \bf", what font face mean and how can I use a good one. Actually, I got this thesis template from one of my senior college and editing it to write mine and very new to Latex.

Comment: At which point was the comment block of the start removed? Do you know where this template came from? You got a copy of the template from your friend rather than a pointer where to get the template **updated**? I wouldn't use it though. See  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports

Comment: The first error in your screenshort is "file ended while scanning use  of \field." This indicates a problem in the bib. Probably you have a % in an abstract field. Correct this first, then delete the bbl and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks and you helped me identify an error in bib file. But that alone didn't help. So, I installed TexMaker and it compiled without any problem. Thanks, everyone, specially Zarco, for your time and ideas.

Answer (score 3):

This is rather an extended comment than an answer:

- apparently you use a very old "template" which use syntax like `\it` `\bf` which is obsolete more than 20 years (however still works somehow...). In text the correct syntax is `\textit{...}` or `{\itshape ...}`, `\textbf{...}` or `{\bfseries ...}`, and in math environments `\mathbf{...}` or `\bm{...}` if you use the `bm` package for bold faces math letters (variables)
- I suspect that variables in bold face means vectors and matrices, if so, why in some equations do you use the notation `\vec{x}`, for example?
- in writing math expression can be handy `physics` or `esdiff` package. they support convenient way to write derivatives, and other math operators, for example the gradient etc.
- I mentioned my problems with `biblatex`: I have problems with my `biblatex` installation (I do not use it), options `maxcitenames` doesn't work (but this seems work for you)
- to eliminate your problems I suggest you to test the following MWE:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{physics}% for make typesetting equations for physics simpler, faster, and more human-readable.

  \usepackage{enumitem}% for simpler customization of used lists
  \setlist[itemize]{label= --}

  \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
  \begin{document}

  \section{Flow due to diurnal}
  \lipsum[66]% for dummy text

      \begin{enumerate}
  \item Improving the bodies \citep[587]{Muha:2018}.

      the present knowledge on this subject by revealing the necessary numerical techniques, modifications, adjustments and improvements.
  \item  Developing a  flow condition.

       This will be efficient and effective in the studies of solid-fluid interaction under buoyant flow scenarios.
  \item  Exploring the values of

      Achieving this objective will unfold a modelling approach, which will be efficient and effective in the studies of scenarios.
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{equation}\label{eq:kernel_gradient}
  \langle \grad f(\vec{x})\rangle=-\int_Vf(\vec{x'})\grad' W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)\dd\vec{x'},
  \end{equation}
  or using bold faces variables for vectors (recommended):        
  \begin{equation}\label{eq:kernel_gradient}
  \langle \grad f(\mathbf{x})\rangle=-\int_V f(\mathbf{x'})\grad' W(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x'},h)\dd\mathbf{x'},
  \end{equation}

      \begin{itemize}
  \item $W$ is usually an even function with respect to $\vec{x}$, it is positive, having the maximum value at $\vec{x}$ and decreases monotonically with the distance from $\vec{x}$;
  \item   \textit{normalization condition}:
      \begin{equation}
      \int_VW(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h)d\vec{x'}=1;
      \end{equation}
  \item   \textit{Dirac-$\delta$ property}:
      \begin{equation}
  \lim_{h\to 0}W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h) = \delta(\vec{x}-\vec{x'})
      \end{equation}
  \item   \textit{compact support}:
      \begin{equation}
  W(\vec{x}-\vec{x'},h) =0 \quad \text{when } |\vec{x}-\vec{x'}|>\kappa h,
      \end{equation}
  \end{itemize}
  \lipsum[66]%for dummy text
  \end{document}
  ```
- if it works, try step-by-stet to add in preamble other used packages (please, use their recent versions) and see if the above *MWE*  (minimal working example) still works
- next step is adding your text to my *MWE*. in text please correct first all what I mentioned in my comments and consider the way how is above the *MWE* written.
- if the above *MWE* doesn't work, than first look at settings in your editor (if it use Unicode encoding) than, if nothing helps, try to reinstall your LaTeX distribution or try to use Overleaf on-line service.
- if my *MWE* doesn't work with  with your `\documentclass`, then it is probably somehow broken or have some own redefinition of `itemize` enviroment. In this case you need to look its code or better use some other, newest "template".

I hope that this extended comment will help you. The *MWE* above produce the following result without any error, bad boxes or warnings:

[image]

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you very much for editing my answer.

Comment: You're welcome! Not sure all I did is correct :):):)